# Cumulative Total by Two Factors Across Multiple Groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've read many SO posts on seemingly similar questions, and the only solution using data.table is not giving expected result.

I have data as follows:

```
temp<-structure(list(App_Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
            3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("Feb 2020", "Mar 2020", Apr 2020", "May 2020", "Jun 2020", "Jul 2020", "Aug 2020", "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Apr 2021", "May 2021", "Jun 2021", "Jul 2021", "Aug 2021", "Sep 2021", "Oct 2021", "Nov 2021", "Dec 2021", "Jan 2022", "Feb 2022", "Mar 2022", "Apr 2022", "May 2022", "Jun 2022", "Jul 2022", "Aug 2022", "Sep 2022", "Oct 2022", "Nov 2022", "Dec 2022", "Jan 2023", "Feb 2023"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), STARlevel = c("STAR 2", "STAR 1", "STAR 2", "STAR 3", "STAR 4", "STAR 1", "STAR 2", "STAR 3", "STAR 4", "STAR 1", "STAR 2", 
  "STAR 3", "STAR 4", "STAR 1"),  newfacil = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 25L, 34L, 51L, 36L, 11L, 16L, 19L, 41L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

temp$App_Month<-factor(temp$App_Month,levels=c("Feb 2020", "Mar 2020", "Apr 2020", "May 2020", "Jun 2020", "Jul 2020", "Aug 2020", "Sep 2020","Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Apr 2021", "May 2021","Jun 2021", "Jul 2021", "Aug 2021", "Sep 2021", "Oct 2021", "Nov 2021", "Dec 2021", "Jan 2022","Feb 2022", "Mar 2022", "Apr 2022", "May 2022", "Jun 2022", "Jul 2022", "Aug 2022", "Sep 2022","Oct 2022", "Nov 2022", "Dec 2022", "Jan 2023", "Feb 2023"),ordered = T)


temp$STARlevel<-factor(temp$STARlevel, levels=c("STAR 1","STAR 2", "STAR 3","STAR 4"),ordered=T )
```

My goal is to group my data and then obtain a running cumulative total for `newfacil` for across months by `STARlevel`. That is, across the months (and years), my accumulated total for `newfacil` should continue to increase by STAR level.

The correct result should look like this:

```
correct<-c(2,1,6,3,3,26,42,54,39,37,45,73,80,50)
temp<-cbind(temp,correct)
```

I tried various dplyr solutions, and also this:

```
library(data.table)
tempDT<-data.table::data.table(temp)
tempDT[ ,CumulativeSums:=cumsum(newfacil),by=list(STARlevel,App_Month)]
tempDT  # compare to column `correct` - the result I want
```

You can see the tempDT result is not what I hoped for.

Why isn't this simply `group-by` and `mutate` with `cumsum`?

Comment: remove ```App_Month``` from by group should work

Comment: That DOES work; thanks!  Do you want to post the answer?